# Dynamic position of images according to their size

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have various images in my Photo Gallery. But when I display the photos of a particular album, it is very difficult to maintain the image size with its position. If I leave the image size(height or width) dynamic, the images are positioned here and there (scattered).And when I fix the size of the images (say height:200 width:200).. The thumbnails looks so dull. What would be a solution to this?

I tried to calculate the height and width of every image and then position them according to it. I am having problems , but I think I can make it work that way. Is there any other better option.

I want the images to be positioned like in this website http://gses.snu.ac.kr/eng/ .

UPDATE
And my images can be added or deleted dynamically.

Comment: Are the images to be displayed dynamic? i.e. can new ones be 'uploaded' or are they fixed. The site you pointed to has probably never changed them or they have a very strict way of changing them. The design requires that each image be of a specific size and order so as to not break that layout. In short that layout is not very well suited to a dynamic set of images due to its layout.

Comment: @paul sullivan My images can be added and deleted dynamically.

Comment: Then I would say you are out of luck. You see that design has a lot of images that 'overflow' and force images to wrap around the overflowed images (the tall ones). You would be in a for a hell of a headache trying to do that as a liquid (not fixed) layout. If you manage to accomplish it in javascript or straight css I would be amazed

Comment: As an aside I think it could be done but... I recently implemented a 'brick laying application' which took images of brick faces and built a wall design including bricks on their side. I tell you now this was pretty complicated and required a lot of playing around. Your idea is very similar.

Comment: @PaulSullivan Ya.. lets see.. I dont think that I can make it work.. but i will try.. Thanks any way..
and one question about stackpverflow, how do i keep my account active?
My last account was deactivated. Was it because I ask these sort of questions.?

Comment: No it will be because you probably didn't visit in a long time and had you account culled as a result

Comment: @PaulSullivan I got this message that I can ask no more questions in stackoverflow. That was quite Funny :D .

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a way to both vertical & horizontal align random images with CSS. Believe me I've tried everything. Ultimately all you can do is make a standard size "box" that fits the largest image you expect to have and display the image in it. That, at least, will give you a sense of order.

Here's an example of what I mean:

http://www.marianoagency.com/payment

I'd love to be able to place the image directly in the center (easy with tables), but I've been unable to accomplish it with pure CSS due to the variable size of the dynamic images.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also have been using that same thing for the gallery of one website I developed http://www.artudio.org/gallery.php .
Another thing that I have been doing is create a div smaller than the image to be included inside it and setting the overflow:none ;
In this way, I can include any image and would not worry about the dull appearance but it will crop that particular image.
Not a appropriate approach but can be used to make the thing work.

Comment: I found a website where the images are loaded dynamically but yet are positioned appropriately. I am still figuring out how it can be done.
Any suggestions 
http://pinterest.com/all/?category=technology